# Throw error if firebase document doesn't exist

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise

Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I want to first check if a document exists before continuing on with my function, and if it doesn't exist,  I throw an error. But that error never gets caught? Here is the function that I want to throw the error:

```
class StoreGateway {
  async addCustomerToStore(
    customerId: string
  ) {
    const customer = await fb.customersCollection.doc(customerId).get();
    if (customer.exists) {
      //do other stuff
    } else {
      console.log("customer didn't exist")
      return new Error("customer didn't exist");
    }
  }
}
```

and how i'm calling the function:

```
StoreGateway.addCustomerToStore(
  req.params.customerId
)
  .then(() => {
    res
      .status(200)
      .json("Success");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  });
}
```

Now if the document doesn't exist, the console does print "customer doesn't exist", but I never get the status 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are just returning a error not rejecting the promise. You can follow the following two methods to reject a promise.

###### 1. Throw new Error

```
if (customer.exists) {
    //do other stuff
} else {
    console.log("customer didn't exist")
    throw new Error("customer didn't exist");
}
```

##### 2. Return a rejected promise

```
if (customer.exists) {
    //do other stuff
} else {
    console.log("customer didn't exist")
    return Promise.reject(new Error("customer didn't exist"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was getting thrown off because I wasn't seeing the error message, but I had to do `res.status(500).json(err.message);`